# Dataflow Data Factury Azure - Exists

Tags: azure, dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have been trying to create a dataflow to check “changed data” between two sources, the staging table and the target one. I want to clean all the possible duplicates from the staging table to sink it in the target one.
I have tried different ways, without success. I am wondering if there is a safe and efficient way to do what I want.

Source table is an external table with 77 columns
Target table is a physical one with 77 columns
Datatype of both columns are the same

**First try:**

I tried through “exists/does not exist” activity.
The first try, I set a “does not exist” activity with all the columns of the table (staging) equal all the columns from the target table. Therefore, I intended to sink all the cases that do not match the setting mentioned.
Example:

```
STAGING@COLUMNA  ==  TARGET@COLUMNA  &&
STAGING @COLUMNB  ==  TARGET @COLUMNB  &&
STAGING@COLUMNC  ==  TARGET@COLUMNC
```

...

Result: It did not work and let all the duplicates get inside the target table. It seems that the comparison with columns not varchar is not that good. I tried to use coalesce and trim, but without success again

**Second Try**

Therefore, I tried to create a row signature with:

Derived column for both source (staging and target)

```
sha2(256,COLUMNA,COLUMNB,COLUMNC … )
```

DOES NOT EXIST ACTIVITY

STAGING@FINGERPRINT == TARGET@FINGERPRINT

Result: Once again it did not work. My test was with more than 10k duplicated rows, and all of them got inside again.

Would anyone have a different approach?

Comment: Make sure you are using all significant fields or use the technique in the script snippets here that includes all columns for a row fingerprint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#distinct-row-using-all-columns

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are here:

- Distinct rows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryYo8UFUgTI
- Dedupe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOi26ETtPTw
- Hashing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Id82NZo9hxM

Comment: It did not work. I don't know why, but it is not recognizing the similarity of the values. Maybe because it has a negative value or a few symbols. Anyway, any mentioned example provided me with a safe solution.